# gradle build not working

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build an existing project from GitHub. It is my company's GitHub account so I cannot share the details however, I am seeking a little guidance because I am a newbie.

The project consists of a main project with an app folder and some gradle files.

It is dependent on some other repositories each having their own version of gradle. How should I proceed?

Comment: If the build is failing directly from a Github pull, then that's a problem. Otherwise, I'm sure you can provide the code you added or any Gradle file/error  once you remove identifying information

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio (v2.1.x), you can import the project from the Start dialog or from "File->New->Import Project..."

About the Gradle repositories, in the root folder it's common to have a buld.gradle with the repository configured.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

It must be enough for download all your dependencies defined on your build.gradle. If are some local JAR dependecies it must be placed on the folders defined on the same config file. You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) page for more info.